# Able to upload, download, and delete but not list in Azure Blob Container

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have a service in C# where I try to list all the files in a directory.

```
CloudBlobDirectory dir = container.GetDirectoryReference(path);
var res = await dir.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(continuationToken); <-- Error is thrown on this line
```

I have confirmed that the directory exists, that the path is correct, and that it has files in it.

However, I'm getting this error: `The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.`

I am accessing the blob with a SAS key that has all permissions (read, write, delete, list). Listing files works perfectly fine when I use the storage emulator, but not when I'm connected to an actual azure resource. What could be the issue?

Comment: This error would usually mean there’s an issue with the SAS token itself. Can you please share the code for generating the token? Also please share the SAS token (you can obfuscate the sig part of the token). Also, please share the complete code where this token is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can only list when I have account-level access, instead of container-level like what I had before. I generated a new SAS key off the Azure portal, for `https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/` instead of `https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>`, and was able to list. I have no idea why as this wasn't written in the docs anywhere.